# background drawable does not fit in bound of TextView in Android

Tags: android, textview, android-widget, android-background

I made a TextView which has attributes of background, gravity and so on.
and i made a drawable resource file for the TextView's background.
and this is the xml.
[image]

and i added the drawable resource into background of the TextView.
[image]

but the problem is, the background doesn't fit in Textview's bound.
please look at this photo.

[image]

there is a gap very slightly.
the background color area is upper than TextView's area.
so i tried to use includeFontPadding attribute but it didn't work.
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to check this on real device/emulator, not on preview in AS. use [Show Layout Bounds](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options) option from developer options for verification, make some full-resolution screen shot and check on it. it will be properly placed

content of any `View`, including its background, is always places inside its bounds. really, always, its just impossible to get outside with a single pixel (due to layout building and drawing mechanism)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the code. In the Design Editor, it shows like this when we use any background drawable with any view. There is not any kind of a glitch.